# How to pass a customer email in a stripe webhook 'invoice.payment_succeeded' event?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am calling a function in case 'invoice.payment_succeeded' that requires the customer's email as input.
How do I get the email from this event object?
the app is nodejs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All invoice webhook events (including `invoice.payment_succeeded`) will contain the related Invoice object in the event payload, under the `object.data` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data).

The Invoice object will contain a `customer_email` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-customer_email) which is a snapshot of the `email` field on the associated Customer object at the time of the invoice.